# Custom authentication to OpenFire server using XMPP on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, openfire

I just started a new project that uses opneFire and xmpp, the project uses the User Service Plugin, so I just implemented the register new user method that looks like:

```
NSString *urlToCall = @"http://MyIP:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=BigSecretKey&username=testUser&password=testPass&name=testName&email=test@gmail.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToCall];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([responseString  isEqual: @"<result>ok</result>\r\n"]) {
    NSLog(@"user created");

} else {
   NSLog( @"user NOT created");
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
```

That works as expected, but now I am stuck on the login, because I don't know what to use, a GET or a Post method and how should it look, in my opinion it should be a POST one but I don't know how the standard openFire link looks like, I suppose it should take the username and concatenate it to obtain the jid and the password and pass this two informations to the url.

Thanks in advance